# VLOOKUP matching 2 fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I want to display a value from another spreadsheet based on matches of two adjacent cells.

Data where the return value is needed:

[image: data where the retun value is needed]

Data with the values I want to return:

[image: data with the values i want to return]

I am trying to retrieve certain data from another spreadsheet if it matches 2 components of the data where I want the value to be returned. Is this possible to do with Vlookup?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use [`Index/Match` with multiple criteria](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Check out some other posts. A picture is worth a thousand words. You are speaking in theory and nobody wants to discuss theoretically. Put up your data and explain specifically what you've done so far and where you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

To use Vlookup you have to concatenate the 2 columns corresponding to your criteria, create a new column before A (A will become B, B will become C and C will become D)
In A1 write =Concatenate(B1,C1) and drag it down
In G1 write =IFERROR(Vlookup(concatenate(E1,F1),$A$1:$D$6,4,False),"")
A1:D6 is the new array table of Data modify it to your sheet name (picture 2)
4 is the column number (D) for result
False to have the exact match

Another method is Index/Match without modifying your Data in G1 write:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(sheet2!$A$1:$C$6,MATCH(1,(sheet2!$A$1:$A$6=E1)*(sheet2!$B$1:$B$6=F1),0),3),"")`

press `Ctrl` + `Shift` +`Enter` at the same time (array formula)
A1:C6 your Data in Sheet2 (picture 2)
1 in match correspond to True for the multiplication of the 2 columns
0 for exact match
3 the third column for result
and you can drag it down